# How to write a console menu in ANSI/ISO C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a simple program in c, where the user has to choose between several options:

```
char command = '1';
while(command!='0') {
    printf("Menu:\n");
    printf("1. First option\n");
    printf("2. Second option\n");
    printf("0. Exit\n");
    printf("Choose: 0,1,2?: ");
    command = getchar();
    while(getchar()!='\n');     
    switch(command) {
        case '0': break;
        case '1': functionCall1(); break; 
        case '2': functionCall2(); break;
    }
}
```

The problem with my code is, that every second time I enter 1,2 or 0, nothing happens, only the menu prints itself again. With the debugger I can see, that the value of **command**, after command = getchar() equals '', every second time. I thought that eating the newline character is enough?

Comment: Your example runs OK for me as is, and if I have functionCall1 and functionCall2 print something, I can see that it works as advertised. But maybe it's different with your compiler?

Comment: The type of `command` must be `int` not `char`, to be able to hold `EOF`. Note that when someone enters EOF (e.g. Ctrl-D on Unix), your program spins in the `while (getchar() != '\n') ;` loop.

Comment: a `do { ... } while('0' != command);` would be a more elegant construct

Comment: @guga I don't feel that Yoda conditions are elegant at all.

Comment: Yes i tested it with simplified funtionCall1 and functionCall2 and it works ok, obviously the problem is with my functions. Thank you guys

Comment: @MrLister, -1 for your comment! :p Nothing like the right construct to improve program intelligibility! Of course one need to understand what is appropriate and when...

Answer (score 6):

Try my customized menu, I implemented it to make my life easier when I work with programs which contains multiple choices operations.
Menu is navigable (arrows:up, down, left, right), and for making a selection you only need to press enter key, menu orientation can be set vertically or horizontally, padding can be set to a group of items(childrens), child starting position, and update with delay.

**Menu call example (vertically):**

```
int response = menu("OPTIONS","[*]","->",
                    1,3,3,0,5,
                    "PROFILES","ACTIVITY","VIDEO","SOUND","GAMEPLAY");
```

The most important thing is because function implementation takes only 60 lines of code.

**Menu implementation:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <windows.h>

// LXSoft
// mod: cui/menu_021
// stdarg.h  -> used for variable list of arguments (va_list, va_start ...)
// windows.h -> used for Sleep function, for *nix use unistd.h

typedef unsigned short int usint_t;
// Menu function prototype
int menu(char* name, char* prefix, char* cursor, usint_t orientation,
         usint_t padding, usint_t start_pos, usint_t delay,
         usint_t num_childs, ...);

int main()
{
    int response = menu("OPTIONS","[*]","->",1,3,3,0,5,
                        "PROFILES","ACTIVITY","VIDEO","SOUND","GAMEPLAY");
    switch(response)
    {
        case 1:
            // doSomethingFoo1();
        break;
        case 2:
            //doSomethingFoo2();
        break;
        /*
         * .
         * .
         * .
         * case n:
         * break;
         */
    }
    printf("\nYour choice is: %d", response);
    return 0;
}

// Menu implementation
int menu
(
    char *name,        // Menu name (eg.: OPTIONS)
    char *prefix,      // Menu prefix (eg.: [*])
    char *cursor,      // Menu cursor (eg.: ->)
    usint_t orient,    /*
                        * Menu orientation vertical or horzontal.
                        * 0 or false for horizontal
                        * 1 or true for vertical
                        */
    usint_t padding,   // Menu childrens padding (eg.: 3)
    usint_t start_pos, // Menu set active child (eg.: 1)
    usint_t delay,     // Menu children switch delay
    usint_t childs,    // Number of childrens
    ...                /*
                        * Variable list of arguments char* type.
                        * Name of the childrens.
                        */
)
{
    va_list args;
    int tmp=0,pos;
    char chr;
    usint_t opt=start_pos;
    char* format=malloc
    (
        (
            strlen(name)+strlen(prefix)+strlen(cursor)+
            3+ /* menu suffix (1 byte) and backspace (2 bytes) */
            (2*childs)+ /* newline (2 bytes) times childs */
            (padding*childs)+ /* number of spaces times childs */
            childs*15 /* children name maxlen (15 bytes) times childs*/
        )*sizeof(char)
    );
    do
    {
        if(tmp!=0)chr=getch();
        if(chr==0x48||chr==0x4B)
            (opt>1&&opt!=1)?opt--:(opt=childs);
        else if(chr==0x50||chr==0x4D)
            (opt>=1&&opt!=childs)?opt++:(opt=1);
        else {/* do nothing at this time*/}
        strcpy(format,"");
        strcat(format,prefix);
        strcat(format,name);
        strcat(format,":");
        va_start(args,childs);
        for (tmp=1;tmp<=childs;tmp++)
        {
            (orient)?strcat(format,"\n"):0;
            pos=padding;
            while((pos--)>0) strcat(format," ");
            if(tmp==opt)
            {
                strcat(format,"\b");
                strcat(format,cursor);
            }
            strcat(format,va_arg(args,char*));
        }
        /*if(tmp!=childs)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"%s: recieved NULL pointer argument,"
                           " child not named", __func__);
            return -1;
        }*/
        Sleep(delay);
        system("cls");
        printf(format);
        va_end(args);
    }while((chr=getch())!=0x0D);
    return opt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you should try to use `int x` as a key to use a desirable command, may be like that:

> ```
> while(x != 0)
> {
>     scanf("%d", &x);
>     switch (x)
>     {
>         printf("input '2' to...\n");
>         printf("input '3' to...\n");
>         printf("input '4' to...\n");
>         printf("input '5' to...\n");
>         printf("input '6' to...\n");
>         case 1:
>             head = Enqueue(head);
>             break;
>         case 2:
>             head1 = spisokMagazinovScenoiMensheiZadannoi(head, head1);
>             break;
>         case 3:
>             head1 = udalenieElementa(head1);
>             break;
>         case 4:
>             head1 = addNewMagazin(head1);
>             break;
>         case 5:
>             head1 = addNewMagazin(head1);
>             break;
>         case 6:
>             printToTheFile(head);
>             break;
>
>     }
> }
> ```

I used it in my previous homework. Hope it will be usefull for you

Answer (score 0):

it's my exaple of func menu.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <windows.h>

int menu(char s[][80],int kolop){
    int pos = 0,push = 0,i,flag = 0;
    printf("MENU:\n>");
    puts(s[0]);
    for(i = 1;i < kolop;i++){
        printf(" ");
        puts(s[i]);
    }
    printf("Enter 5 to move the cursor down 8 to the top(Press ENTER to end)\n");
    do{
            if(flag == 1)
              printf("Error try to press 5,8 or ENTER\n");
            push = getch();
            flag = 1;
    }
    while(push != 56 && push != 53 && push != 13);
    flag = 0;
    system("cls");
    while(push != 13){
        if(push == 53){
            puts("MENU:");
            for(i = 0;i < kolop;i++){
                if(i == pos + 1 && flag == 0){
                    printf(">");
                    puts(s[i]);
                    flag = 1;
                    pos++;
                }
                else{
                    printf(" ");
                    puts(s[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        if(push == 56){
            puts("MENU:");
            for(i = 0;i < kolop;i++){
                if(i == pos - 1 && flag == 0){
                    printf(">");
                    puts(s[i]);
                    flag = 1;
                    pos--;
                }
                else{
                    printf(" ");
                    puts(s[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        _flushall();
        printf("Enter 5 to move the cursor down 8 to the top(Press ENTER to end)\n");
        flag = 0;
        do{
            if(flag == 1)
              printf("Error try to press 5,8 or ENTER\n");
            push = getch();
            flag = 1;
        }
        while(push != 56 && push != 53 && push != 13);
        flag = 0;
        system("cls");
    }
    pos++;
    return pos;
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    char s[][80] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7"};
    int i,pos = 0,push,flag = 0;
    pos = menu(s,7);
    printf("%d",pos);
    //system("cls");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nit, where is the conversion necessitating `printf()` in `printf("MENU:\n>");`? Wouldn't `fputs("MENU\n>", stdout);` accomplish the same thing in a non-variadic way? (yes, a good compiler will optimize for you). `system("cls");` is 100% non-portable and unnecessary (it just outputs a screen worth of `'\n'` chars) `char s[][80]` seems a bit excessive for 14-bytes of data (including the `'\0'` chars -- which it is unclear why single-character string-literals are used) What is `58` and`53` and `13`? Did you mean `'5'`, `':'` and `'\r'`? If so, use the character literals (more readable)